# Typescript - catching an Error from a Promise throwing an Error within an asynchronous method

Tags: typescript

Throwing an Error in a Promise, even within an asynchronous method, is maybe best done via reject (new Error( 'message'));

How can I catch an Error that is thrown within an asynchronous method in a Promise?

PURPOSE: when an (runtime) Error happens in an asynchronous method (inside a Promise) how can I best handle this?

**A simplified example** will show you exactly what I mean:

```
const myPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    // Simulating an Error in an Asynchronous method ...
    throw new Error('Something bad happened');
  }, 1000);
} );
console.log( 'Started');
try {
  myPromise
  .then( res => console.log( res) )
  .catch( err => console.log( 'Promise.catch: ' + (err as Error).message))
  .finally( () => console.log( 'All done') );  
} catch( error) {
  console.log( 'Error in promise catched: ' + (error as Error).message);
}
console.log( 'Ended');
```

In the mean time I found a [great article](https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc) saying:

> If the runtime error occurs in the callback function of an async call
> (inside the executor function), then the error will won’t be caught

**So, the solution is simply** putting a try catch block in the asynchronous method if you suspect it to give runtime exceptions/errors?

```
const myPromise2 = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    try {
      throw new Error(' 2 - Simulating something real bad happened');
    }
    catch( erx) {
      reject( ' 2 - In promise error: ' + (erx as Error).message);
    }
  }, 100);
} );
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking here. if you want to throw an error within a promise, use `reject`, if you want to catch that error, you use the error handler. unless you want to use async / await, then you can do things more like what you're trying to do. if you're trying to catch an error within the promise, then put your try / catch inside the promise.

Comment: use `const wait = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));` and then `const myPromise = wait(1000).then(() => { throw ... });`

Comment: Tx. Changed the question. I just want to simulate (via a simplistic example) when inside the asynchronous method an Error is thrown.

Comment: the solution in your post is correct. try / catch inside the promise.

Comment: @bryan60 - You can post it as a solution and I will ^+1 / solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is given by **@bryan60** in a comment. So if @bryan60 provides the answer, I am happy to delete this one.

**@bryan60** wrote in a comment: "the solution in your post is correct. try / catch inside the promise."

So, the solution is in code:

```
const myPromise2 = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    try {
      throw new Error(' 2 - Simulating something real bad happened');
    }
    catch( erx) {
      reject( ' 2 - In promise error: ' + (erx as Error).message);
    }
  }, 100);
} );
```